# Use an Archived version on XCode

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I have an app that I haven't update in a while and I want to update it to iOS 14, there is a mismatch in my github repo and the archive version number that I have published, maybe I forgot to commit the last update I did. How can I use the local archive version I have on my computer or download the current one in Apple Store?
On Github I see version 3.01 and my local has 3.1.0

Thanks

Comment: The archives you see are only compiled binaries, so even if you could download them, they wouldn't really help in restoring your source code.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to restore it? My git commits are behind :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the archive version of the app store is inaccessible and only the version control is the one that can be use for restoration purposes. So no option available.